# Why is VS Code's Prettier extension replacing spaces with {" "} in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

Every time I save (format on save) a file, Prettier decides to add me this (talking about coding in JS with React): `{" "}` or `{' '}`

Why does this happen? Is it a good thing? If not, how can I make it stop happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's one of the things that can't be *prettier* and we probably have to get used to it.

If you check the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals-1), you can see that with JSX trailing and leading whitespaces on a line are removed:

> JSX removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line. It also
> removes blank lines. New lines adjacent to tags are removed; new lines
> that occur in the middle of string literals are condensed into a
> single space.

If you need a space to show up between text and a following element on the next line, you have to add `{" "}`. You just can't avoid it. The ugly spaces are actually semantically important to JSX.

Original:

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>There is <strong>no problem</strong> with long texts without inline elements starting on new lines. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vero enim eos iste! Odio deserunt id quam.</li>
    <li>But if there are inline HTML elements on new lines... Soluta culpa dolor <a href="#officia">officia omnis</a> fugiat ipsa! Corporis, ex amet hic incidunt explicabo? Alias <strong>libero temporibus, corporis recusandae</strong> <em>voluptatibus</em> eligendi.</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Formatted:

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li>
      There is <strong>no problem</strong> with long texts without inline
      elements starting on new lines. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vero enim eos iste! Odio deserunt id quam.
    </li>
    <li>
      But if there are inline HTML elements on new lines... Soluta culpa dolor{" "}
      <a href="#officia">officia omnis</a> fugiat ipsa! Corporis, ex amet hic
      incidunt explicabo? Alias{" "}
      <strong>libero temporibus, corporis recusandae</strong>{" "}
      <em>voluptatibus</em> eligendi.
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>;
```