# Auto-formatting adds the special characters like {""} in visual-studio-code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

i'm a beginner in the react and using visual studio currently but everytime we write a .js file for any component and using the visual studio shortcuts (Format on save) with prettier extension.it formats but it does add some weird characters in between.

```
const AppOne=(prop)=> {
 return (<img src=prop.path/><br/>);
}
export default AppOne;
```

when we use auto-format it does change like below

```
 const AppOne=(prop)=> {
     return (
     {""}
     <img src=prop.path/>{""}
     <br/>
     );
    }
    export default AppOne;
```

Why does it behave this way and what is the purpose of `{""}`. Please let me know if anyone else have faced the similar issue and how to make it behave normally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly https://stackoverflow.com/q/65326159/11107541 ? if you have a space between the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you kept some space in between `jsx elements`, then spcing (`{""}`) adds to fill the gap.