# VSCode adding {' '} for white space

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lately, VSCode has been adding {' '} to my code.  Not sure what setting I need to disable.

```
           />
        )}
        <CardFooter>
            {' '}
```

Comment: Is this coming from an extension? Does it happen when you restart with extensions disabled? Or what do you find when you do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect)?

Comment: Thank you - lint was adding it if I had a space between one Element and the other
<CardFooter> <Box>
lint changed it to
<CardFooter>{' '}
   <Box>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier in VS Code is adding {" "} everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326159/prettier-in-vs-code-is-adding-everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

issue was with lint, it was replacing trailing spaces with {' '}

Comment: please add a marketplace link for the extension you are referring to.